# Accord de « en présence de »

Tags: grammaire, expressions, accord

Faut-il accorder l'expression `en présence de` en fonction de ce qui suit?

Par exemple, écrit-on

> *en présence de mon frère et de ma soeur*

ou

> *en présences de mon frère et de ma soeur*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*en présence de* est invariable car il s’agit d'une forme raccourcie de *en la présence de*, aujourd'hui vu comme plutôt ampoulé. On met aussi l'article si un adjectif accompagne *présence*.

Comment: Ne dirait-on pas: _en les présences de_?

Comment: Non. Grosso modo, *présence* ici est un nom d'état indénombrable (on dit de même *sous l'autorité de* peu importe le nombre d'autorités en question), donc invariable dans la majorité des cas.

Answer (score 1):

La première solution : *en présence de* est une locution invariable.